# Remote desktop is crashing Petrel software

Tags: 2d, config, remote-desktop, petrel

We have several users that are experiencing crashing in Petrel while using the Remote Desktop Connection application.  Users can connect to a rack machine, but simple tasks like moving in a 2D window locks up the application.  It is difficult to replicate the issue.  It is random times that it occurs.  It happens in multiple projects for multiple users.  Is there a setting for RDP or in Petrel or in Windows that will resolve this issue? We are using Windows 10 and version 2020.4 of Petrel.
Thank you.

Attempted to reconfigure the compression of the remoteFX data.  This did not resolve the issue.